# setting marker for given period time fails

Tags: ros, rviz, markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to visualize a specific marker for few period of time, but when i try this code it shows error:

```
 error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘visualization_msgs::Marker_<std::allocator<void> >::_lifetime_type {aka ros::Duration}’ and ‘int’)
     points.scale.y = 0.01; points.lifetime=1;
```

My codes are:

```
 visualization_msgs::Marker points, line_strip, line_list;
     points.header.frame_id = line_strip.header.frame_id = line_list.header.frame_id = "/camera_depth_frame";    points.header.stamp = line_strip.header.stamp = line_list.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
        points.ns = line_strip.ns = line_list.ns = "lines";
    points.action =line_strip.action = line_list.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;
    points.pose.orientation.w = line_strip.pose.orientation.w = line_list.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
    points.id = 0;
    line_strip.id = 1;
    line_list.id = 2;
    points.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::POINTS;
    line_strip.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::LINE_STRIP;

line_list.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::LINE_LIST;
points.scale.x = 0.01; 
points.scale.y = 0.01; points.lifetime=1;
```

How can i use this lifetime parameter? For eg. here i was trying to set lifetime of points as 1 sec.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243493/setting-marker-for-given-period-time-fails/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Read the error message. You cannot set (that is, use the `=` operator) the field `points.lifetime` (which is an object of type `ros::Duration`) to an `int`.

You can, however, set `points.lifetime` to `ros::Duration(1.0)`.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2016-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-09-10**:
i have did that also points.lifetime=ros::Duration(0.5) but the points were staying for more than 0.5 sec so. But i'll try it again, re test.

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-09-11**:
ok it looks like it works, but the previous points are again appearing after being replaced by another point.